# Trying to parse JSON data from URL : Unable to resolve host "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com": No address associated with hostname

Tags: android, json

i'm trying  to parse JSON DATA from URL and display it in a listView but i'm getting this error :

> 03-27 20:53:04.830 13960-14086/com.example.samplejson E/HttpHandler:
>   IOException: Unable to resolve host "jsonplaceholder.typicode.com": No
>   address associated with hostname
>
> 03-27 20:53:04.830 13960-14086/com.example.samplejson E/MainActivity: 
>   Response from url: null
>
> 03-27 20:53:04.830 13960-14086/com.example.samplejson E/MainActivity:
>   Couldn't get json from server.

I have already added this line in my **androidmanifest.xml**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Here is my MainActivity.java file :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
private ListView lv;

// URL to get contacts JSON
private static String url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    contactList = new ArrayList<>();

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    new GetContacts().execute();
}

/**
 * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
 */
private class GetContacts extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Showing progress dialog
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

        // Making a request to url and getting response
        String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

        Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

        if (jsonStr != null) {
            try {


                // Getting JSON Array node
                JSONArray contacts = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

                // looping through All Contacts
                for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                    String id = c.getString("id");
                    String name = c.getString("name");
                    String email = c.getString("email");
                    String username = c.getString("username");
                    String phone = c.getString("phone");

                   /* // Phone node is JSON Object
                    JSONObject phone = c.getJSONObject("phone");
                    String mobile = phone.getString("mobile");
                    String home = phone.getString("home");
                    String office = phone.getString("office");
 */
                        // tmp hash map for single contact
                    HashMap<String, String> contact = new HashMap<>();

                    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                    contact.put("id", id);
                    contact.put("name", name);
                    contact.put("email", email);
                    contact.put("phone", phone);

                    // adding contact to contact list
                    contactList.add(contact);
                }
            } catch (final JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         * */
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this, contactList,
                R.layout.item_list, new String[]{"nom", "email",
                "tel"}, new int[]{R.id.name,
                R.id.email, R.id.phone});

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

}
}
```

HttpHandler Class :

```
public class HttpHandler {

private static final String TAG = HttpHandler.class.getSimpleName();

public HttpHandler() {
}

public String makeServiceCall(String reqUrl) {
    String response = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(reqUrl);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        // read the response
        InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        response = convertStreamToString(in);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (ProtocolException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "ProtocolException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return response;
}

private String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line).append('\n');
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}


}
```

Any recommendations ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IOException Unable to resolve host,No address associated with hostname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38935799/ioexception-unable-to-resolve-host-no-address-associated-with-hostname)

Comment: what duplicate please ?

Answer (score 8):

The problem may occur due to no internet connection availability.

So, just reverify once your device(where the app is running) internet connection. If it's off, turn it on.

Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If the problem still persists even after turning WiFi/Internet Connection on/off. Try switching off the device and close the emulator and rerun the app.
It worked for me.